# how to configure CQ Apache sling resource resolver factory for multiple domains

Tags: aem

I have two domains and content path something like below
domain1.com/content/abc/en-US/home.html,
domain2.com/content/xyz/kr-KR/home.html

i have defined below URL mapping configuration inside CQ publish instance -->Felix console-->Apache Sling resolver factory

/content/abc/:/
/content/xyz/:/

The above configuration removing the /content/abc,/cotent/xyz from the URL(shortening the URL)
i have rewrite rule defined to redirect www.domain1.com to domain1.com/en-US/home.html and www.domain2.com to domain2.com/kr-KR/home.html..all these working fine..

But my problem is ,i can also able to access domain2.com/en-US/home.html from domain2 though i don't have en-US inside domain2(we should see 404 page). how do i restrict this . i know it's happening because of resource resolver mapping. Any help would be appreciate!!! pls let me know if you're not clear about my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some thing that needs to be controlled at the web server level. The domain only takes the request to CQ's server.Since both domains point to the same server , as long as the path resolves to a correct location it will return the page. Cognifide's blog has a great post on this. Here is an excerpt from that blog that is relevant to your question

> Because users are able to enter a full content path after a given domain name, e.g. geometrixx.com/content/geometrixx/en/products.html, they may as well get a page that belongs to some other domain, e.g. geometrixx.com/content/geometrixx/fr/products.html. In order to avoid such a situation, we need to check all requests for path beginning with /content and reject these which are not related to any campaign, DAM or a current domain:
>
> > `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/content`
> >
> > `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/campaigns`
> >
> > `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/dam`
> >
> > `RewriteRule !^/content/geometrixx/en - [R=404,L,NC]`

It makes use of apache httpd re-write module to send 404 responses when pages that aren't supposed to be on that domain are requested. The link to the blog post is [multidomain mapping in cq5](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/multidomain-cq-mappings-and-apache-configuration/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to fix this issue with above rewrite conditions.